# How to extract a value from JSON using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, json

Sorry I am at a loss here. I dont have a clue about Javascript. I am trying few things based on what I can find on the net. In the meantime if any of you can help me out here that will be wonderful.

Please see the JSON below. I have cut it down to just 3 items but it can be around 50. I am looking to extract the id 7514 if the customFieldId is 3 or 3854 if the customFieldId is 1.

```
{
"items": [
    {
        "id": 3854,
        "customFieldId": 1,
        "customField": {
            "links": [
                {
                    "rel": "canonical",
                    "href": "https://stgxilinx.learn.taleo.net/learn.rest/v1/learnCenters/178410/userCustomFields/1"
                }
            ]
        },
        "value": "Yes",
        "links": [
            {
                "rel": "canonical",
                "href": "https://stgxilinx.learn.taleo.net/learn.rest/v1/memberships/3487/customFieldValues/3854"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 7514,
        "customFieldId": 3,
        "customField": {
            "links": [
                {
                    "rel": "canonical",
                    "href": "https://stgxilinx.learn.taleo.net/learn.rest/v1/learnCenters/178410/userCustomFields/3"
                }
            ]
        },
        "value": "No",
        "links": [
            {
                "rel": "canonical",
                "href": "https://stgxilinx.learn.taleo.net/learn.rest/v1/memberships/3487/customFieldValues/7514"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 93432,
        "customFieldId": 10,
        "customField": {
            "links": [
                {
                    "rel": "canonical",
                    "href": "https://stgxilinx.learn.taleo.net/learn.rest/v1/learnCenters/178410/userCustomFields/10"
                }
            ]
        },
        "value": "Fulltime-Regular",
        "links": [
            {
                "rel": "canonical",
                "href": "https://stgxilinx.learn.taleo.net/learn.rest/v1/memberships/3487/customFieldValues/93432"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

}

Comment: Please post the JavaScript you have tried in a [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can  use `Array.find()` :

```js
var obj = {"items" :[{"id":3854,"customFieldId":1,"customField":{"links":[{"rel":"canonical","href":"https://stgxilinx.learn.taleo.net/learn.rest/v1/learnCenters/178410/userCustomFields/1"}]},"value":"Yes","links":[{"rel":"canonical","href":"https://stgxilinx.learn.taleo.net/learn.rest/v1/memberships/3487/customFieldValues/3854"}]},{"id":7514,"customFieldId":3,"customField":{"links":[{"rel":"canonical","href":"https://stgxilinx.learn.taleo.net/learn.rest/v1/learnCenters/178410/userCustomFields/3"}]},"value":"No","links":[{"rel":"canonical","href":"https://stgxilinx.learn.taleo.net/learn.rest/v1/memberships/3487/customFieldValues/7514"}]},{"id":93432,"customFieldId":10,"customField":{"links":[{"rel":"canonical","href":"https://stgxilinx.learn.taleo.net/learn.rest/v1/learnCenters/178410/userCustomFields/10"}]},"value":"Fulltime-Regular","links":[{"rel":"canonical","href":"https://stgxilinx.learn.taleo.net/learn.rest/v1/memberships/3487/customFieldValues/93432"}]}]};

var customId = 3;
var result = obj.items.find((obj)=> obj.customFieldId === customId);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: This looks neat but I have JSON object with "items":

Answer (score 1):

You could write a simple loop that checks if the customFieldId is either 3 or 1 and if it is, grabs the fieldId for you.

```
for(let i = 0; i < myObj.items.length; i++) {
 let fieldId = myObj.items[i].customFieldId;
 let id = myObj.items[i].id;

 if(fieldId === 3 || fieldId === 1) {
  console.log("The custom field ID is: " + fieldId + " and the id is: " + id);
 }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the an alternate solution.

Comment: No problem, I hope it helped!

Answer (score 1):

you can use filter function to filter out the data from JSON

```
var obj = {"items" :[{"id":3854,"customFieldId":1,"customField":{"links":[{"rel":"canonical","href":"https://stgxilinx.learn.taleo.net/learn.rest/v1/learnCenters/178410/userCustomFields/1"}]},"value":"Yes","links":[{"rel":"canonical","href":"https://stgxilinx.learn.taleo.net/learn.rest/v1/memberships/3487/customFieldValues/3854"}]},{"id":7514,"customFieldId":3,"customField":{"links":[{"rel":"canonical","href":"https://stgxilinx.learn.taleo.net/learn.rest/v1/learnCenters/178410/userCustomFields/3"}]},"value":"No","links":[{"rel":"canonical","href":"https://stgxilinx.learn.taleo.net/learn.rest/v1/memberships/3487/customFieldValues/7514"}]},{"id":93432,"customFieldId":10,"customField":{"links":[{"rel":"canonical","href":"https://stgxilinx.learn.taleo.net/learn.rest/v1/learnCenters/178410/userCustomFields/10"}]},"value":"Fulltime-Regular","links":[{"rel":"canonical","href":"https://stgxilinx.learn.taleo.net/learn.rest/v1/memberships/3487/customFieldValues/93432"}]}]};

function customFieldId(obj) {
   return obj.customFieldId == 3;
}

var result = obj.items.filter(customFieldId);
console.log(result);
```